# Commands required for sound debugging

Tags: sound

I would like to know the output of which commands should be posted when asking a question based on sound errors (no sound / crackling sound etc.)

Comment: http://bootpolish.net/home_howto_debugdebiansound

Comment: This, being a **canonical question** will receive a bounty shortly

Comment: @AmithKK are you sure it is a canonical Q?

Comment: Although OP is 5.7K user he/she hasn't signed on in ~2 years. Further this question is about EOL  Ubuntu version and rather vague to boot. VTC as `not reproducible`.